# How to restrict a web page to load on unsuccessful login?

Tags: php, redirect

How to redirect a web page in PHP if login is successful?

If suppose I know the URL of web page which should be opened only on login, and typed the same URL in `local-host/URL`, it would open this page without login.

How to get rid of it?

Comment: show us your code?

Comment: do a if condition redirect to login if not logged in

Comment: any code to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the login is validated by your php script you can redirect the user by header location method.

```
// Assuming $user->login() returns TRUE in case of success.
if ($user->login()) {
    header('Location: http://yourdomain.tld/loginSuccess.php');
} else {
    header('Location: http://yourdomain.tld/loginError.php');
}
```

If you want access control over loginSuccess.php you should use a cookie/session validation. The $user->login() method should write some data to keep the login active.

For example if you fill the user data in $_SESSION['user'] you can check if the user is logged in adding this code to the top of your pages:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user']) {
    // In case of no data about the user in $_SESSION redirect to error 403 page.
    header('Location: http://yourdomain.tld/403.php');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add some restriction. Now depends that you are using any framework or using custom code. You can check if guest user is trying to access a page then redirect again to login page. Such as if you store user name in db and if user is logged in then check for example:

```
if($loggedUser->username !="" || $loggedUser->username !==NULL)
redirect to next page 
else 
redirect to login page.
```

For more detailed answer, show us your code please.